# App works on Local host but not on appspot

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm working on having a user authenticate on my webpage using Foursquare, once they are redirected back to my webpage the information recieved back is parsed out of the URL. This works perfect on localhost but when I deploy it I get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 634, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/hoosheer/4.349803081119561985/hoosheer_main.py", line 34, in get
    foursquareMethods.foursquareDetails(self)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/hoosheer/4.349803081119561985/foursquareMethods.py", line 40, in foursquareDetails
    doRender(self, '500.html')
  File "/base/data/home/apps/hoosheer/4.349803081119561985/foursquareMethods.py", line 67, in doRender
    handler.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 72, in render
    t = load(template_path, debug)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/template.py", line 100, in load
    template = django.template.loader.get_template(file_name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/loader.py", line 80, in get_template
    template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/loader.py", line 88, in get_template_from_string
    return Template(source, origin, name)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 174, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 273, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 154, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 273, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 132, in do_block
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endblock', 'endblock %s' % block_name))
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 280, in parse
    self.unclosed_block_tag(parse_until)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/template/__init__.py", line 318, in unclosed_block_tag
    raise self.error(None, "Unclosed tags: %s " %  ', '.join(parse_until))
TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tags: endblock, endblock bodycontent
```

**UPDATE**

The line in my code that seems to cause it is when I try to `doRender(self, '500.html')`

This is the doRender method

```
def doRender(handler, tname, values = { }):    
    template_values = dict(values) 
    handler.session = Session()
    if 'access_token' in handler.session: 
        template_values['access_token'] = handler.session['access_token'] 
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), tname)
    handler.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

and the template is as follows

```
{% extends "index.html" %} 
{% block bodycontent %}
Server Error
      <p>
      There has been an error
      </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you redirecting back to appspot instead of localhost?

Comment: The errors tell me it is something wrong with your template. Do you use a different template for localhost? Can you post your template for us to see what might be causing the issue.

Comment: @hyperslug Yes I changed it so that it redirects to appspot

Comment: Including the actual stacktrace - instead of the line of framework code that raises the exception - and the source code and template in question would be helpful.

Comment: @Nick I just updated the Q with everything useful I think, if I leave out the `doRender(self, '500.html')`, it redirects back to the webpage with the following along the top `Set-Cookie: __gads=ID=XX=XX:S=XX Set-Cookie: __qca=P0-XX-XX Set-Cookie: appengine-simple-session-sid=XX; Path=/ Status: 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 15866` you can view this for yourself at hoosheer.appspot.com

Comment: @qwop, is there a new error message?

Comment: @hyperslug there is no error but it does not log the user into the system, instead it just renders the page twice, so that one is on top of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an '/_ah/login_required' handler setup in your app.yaml file?

I'm assuming you've turned on Federated Login to allow Foursquare credentials.  If so you need to define your own login handler in order for it to work on appspot (localhost uses different login handling).

ex:

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: do_openid_login.py
```

Comment: I don't have Federated Login, I didn't even know the login handling was different on appspot, could you link me any documentation that you have found useful? currently I am reading http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary and http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html

Comment: @qwop  Take a look at the authentication section of the 'Users Overview' article ([link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html)).  There is also a more in depth article on using Federated Login with GAE here: ([link](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tags: endblock, endblock bodycontent
```

tells you where at least one issue is.  Close the `endblock`:

```
{% endblock %}
```